# How can I "get" the return value of a function?

Tags: php

What is the syntax to find out in method2 whether method1 one returned true or false?

```
class myClass{
public function method1($arg1, $arg2, $arg3){
   if(($arg1 + $arg2 + $arg3) == 15){
      return true;
   }else{
     return false;
   }
}

public function method2(){
   // how to find out if method1 returned true or false?
}
}

$object = new myClass();
$object->method1(5, 5, 5);
```

Comment: You defined those arguments as normal variables, so it's confusing as to whether you want them to be actual arguments.

Comment: Because I don't know much about OOP. I am just learning.

Comment: There are no objects in your code. This has nothing to do with OOP. It's just basic procedural PHP. Which book are you using?

Comment: These are member functions. They should be inside a class. Otherwise you'll need to take out the `public`s.

Comment: I think he's excluded the class from his snippet...

Comment: @nomaD: Then it is not a valid testcase for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do as you propose you could do it a few ways:

1) Call the method 1 inside method 2

```
public function method2(){
   // how to find out if method1 returned true or false?
   if(method1($a, $b, $c))
   {
       //do something if true
   }
   else
   {
       //do something if false
   }
}
```

2) Call it before method 2 (a bit weird to do it this way but possible and could be needed depending on context)

```
$method1_result = method1($a, $b, $c);

method2($method_result);

//inside method 2 - change the constructor to take the method 1 result. e.g. method2($_method1_result)

if($_method1_result)
{
    //do something if true
}
{
    //do something if false
}
```

If you are only going to need the result of method 1 ONCE (thus the return value of method 1 doesn't change) then and are going to call method 2 many times then you can be more efficient to do it outside of method 2 to save re running the same code (method 1) every time method 2 is called.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
public function method2(){
    if($this->method1(5, 5, 5) == true){
        echo 'method1 returned true';
    } else {
        echo 'method1 returned false';
    }
}

$obj = new myClass();
$obj->method2();
```

Should result in

```
method1 returned true
```